# Access outer class accessor from inner class

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

So I am trying out mixins and some metaprogramming in ruby and can't get this to work for me. I want it to print "Baboon"

```
 module A

  def self.included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def install_A
        include InstanceMethods
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
      class B
         def testB
           #What goes here???
           A.monkey
         end
      end

      attr_accessor :monkey

      def initialize()
         @monkey = "baboon"
      end

      def test
          b = B.new
          puts b.testB
      end
  end
end

class Chimp
  include A
  install_A
end

c = Chimp.new
c.test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B` is its own self-contained class.  It is not associated or connected with any of the other classes or modules except to say that an instance of class `B` happens to be created inside of `InstanceMethods::test`.  Declaring `class B` inside of the definition for `module InstanceMethods` limits the scope of `B` such that it's not visible outside of `InstanceMethods`, but it doesn't connect `B` and `InstanceMethods` in any way.

What you need is to make the module's variable visible inside `B`.  You can implement an `initialize` method for `B` that takes a parameter, and `InstanceMethods::test` can use `b = B.new(@monkey)` to pass the value to `B` (make sure `B::initialize` stores the value as an instance variable).

Comment: Ah, ok. I guess I am carrying over the scoping rules of inner classes from other languages. Thank you!